# VSCode remote-ssh extension: server-side port

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

remote-ssh extension for Visual Studio code installs vscode-server part (from windows to linux in my case)

In Editor, I see there a logs that vscode tests just installed a server by trying to connect to 43311 port.
that port is closed on my server but I have an opened another one.

how to change default port 43311 which remote-ssh vscode-server uses to someone else?

Comment: thank you . but doesn't look it works, I've tried to set the port but error is the same : vscode client tries to check the server on 43311 and no response there. it setting is not working or this is responsible for something other

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I am pretty sure this question is not a duplicate of another one.